# Using IdentityServer4 in tandem with standard MVC Authentication in .Net Core 2.x

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, identityserver4

We have a variety of internal, external, and mobile applications that result in our users having to sign in repeatedly across our organization. I've been working on coming up with a process that will allow us to implement single sign-on across all of our different tools using IdentityServer4, but I've come up with a lot of questions in the process.

In our legacy webforms application, users are logged in through sessions/FormAuthentication. In our new MVC Core application, we use the built-in MVC Authentication (not Identity). In the mobile applications, we sign into the legacy application and pass the session information along with each request. And finally, in our third-party application, it uses windows authentication to sign in.

We're in the process of porting everything over to the new application, but as these things go, everything is moving in chunks. Rather than continuing to implement functionality in the legacy application, we'd like to implement some sort of join authentication in the new platform that allows us to make requests to both the old system and new system. This is how I stumbled across IdentityServer.

Currently, I'm trying to figure out how I can authorize users from the mobile application using IdentityServer and give them full access to the project's endpoints, but simultaneously I want to make sure that we don't adversely affect our current authorization and roles systems that we have in place.

One big issue I run into is that if I apply the minimal configuration to the IdentityServer, but add `#UseIdentityServer` along with `#UseAuthentication` in my startup.cs, we receive errors upon login.

Does this indicate that I will have to rewrite our current authorization algorithms to use identity server across the board, or can I adapt it to work with our current systems?

Here's some of the existing code without IdentityServer implemented.

```
//Startup.cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Cookie authentication changed in .Net Core 2.x, we have to configure everything here.
    services.AddAuthentication(SecurityConstants.CookieAuthenticationScheme)
            .AddCookie(SecurityConstants.CookieAuthenticationScheme, o =>
            {
                o.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
                o.LogoutPath = "Account/LogOff";
                o.AccessDeniedPath = "/Home/Error";
                o.SlidingExpiration = true;
                o.Cookie = new CookieBuilder
                {
                    Name = SecurityConstants.CookieAuthenticationScheme,
                    Expiration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(SecurityConstants.CookieExpirationMinutes),
                    HttpOnly = true
                };
            });
    services.AddAuthentication(o =>
    {
        o.DefaultChallengeScheme = SecurityConstants.CookieAuthenticationScheme;
        o.DefaultSignInScheme = SecurityConstants.CookieAuthenticationScheme;
        o.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = SecurityConstants.CookieAuthenticationScheme;
    });

    // Other standard MVC setup junk removed.
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseSession();

    // routing and irrelevant logic removed
}
```

AccountController Signin

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string userName, string password, string returnUrl = null)
{
    ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
    var authResult = Authentication.Authenticate(userName, password);
    if (authResult.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        var p = new BaseClaimsPrincipal(authResult.AuthenticatedUser);

        await HttpContext.SignInAsync(SecurityConstants.CookieAuthenticationScheme, new ClaimsPrincipal(p));

        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
    }

    ViewBag.Error = "Incorrect Username or Password";

    return View(true);
}
```

The `BaseClaimsPrincipal` above just creates a `GenericIdentity` and `ClaimsIdentity` for use in the signin process.

Comment: One minor note, `UseIdentityServer` includes a call to `UseAuthentication` internally, you won't need both if/when you resolve the problem.